# difference in speed between tensorflow implementations of mfcc and stft

Tags: stft, mfcc

I am trying to preprocess audio clips for a keyword spotting task that uses machine learning models.

The first step is to calculate the spectrogram starting from the waveform and in order to do so I have found that there are two ways within the tensorflow framework.
The first one is to use the `tf.signal` library.

This means the functions:

```py
stft = tf.signal.stft(signals, frame_length, frame_step)
spectrogram = tf.abs(stft)
# matrix computed beforehand
tf.tensordot(spectrogram, linear_to_mel_weight_matrix, 1)
log_mel_spectrogram = tf.math.log(mel_spectrogram + 1.e-6)
mfccs = tf.signal.mfccs_from_log_mel_spectrograms(log_mel_spectrogram)
```

The second is to use `tf.python.ops.gen_audio_ops.` library, which I have seen used in an [example repository](https://github.com/ARM-software/ML-examples/tree/main/tflu-kws-cortex-m/Training), but it is not mentioned in the online tensorflow documentation.
This results in the following code:

```py
# spectrogram computation
spectrogram = audio_ops.audio_spectrogram(
    input=sample,
    window_size=window_size_samples,
    stride=window_stride_samples
    )

# mfcc computation
mfcc_features = audio_ops.mfcc(
    spectrogram=spectrogram,
    sample_rate=sample_rate,
    dct_coefficient_count=dct_coefficient_count
)
```

The problem is that the second one is much faster (~10x). As you can see from this table.

| Operation | tf.signal | audio_ops |
| --- | --- | --- |
| STFT | 5.09ms | 0.35ms |
| Mel+MFCC | 3.05ms | 0.24ms |

In both cases the same parameters were used (window size, hop size, number of coefficients...).
I have done some tests and the output is the same up to the 3rd decimal digit.
My question is: does someone have some experience with these functions or is someone able to explain this behavior?

PS: in order to look at the code for the gen_audio_ops library, since it is not documented online, I looked inside the lib folder of the virtual environment I used for the project and followed the directories.

Comment: How many samples, of which length, are you procesing? If you're assuming it to be more efficient to do something on a GPU, that's only true compared to doing it on a CPU if you don't do an isolated transfer for small pieces of data. This might be the dominant effect here, and hiding everything else, as calculating MFCCs of usually sizes takes *way* less time on a CPU than any of your measured times.

Comment: My goal is to do the processing on a respberry pi, so I would be relying on the CPU.
The samples are 1s recordings and the sampling rate is 16000hz. There are more than 2000 samples in the dataset.The cpu I used to measure the latency in the table is a intel i5 4570, with the governor set in performance mode.
What do you mean by an isolated transfer for small pieces of data? and what should I do to make the mfcc computation take less time than it did?

Comment: ah, OK, I saw tensorflow and assumed you were doing this on a machine with appropriate accelerator (e.g., a GPU or TPU). So, yeah, one has a slow implementation; you'd need to fix that. Question: since this happens in a tensorflow context, is the STFT and the Mel+MFCC operation part of something you train? I.e., is it important that tensorflow knows the gradients of the operation?

Comment: The task is keyword spotting, with a very simple and efficient neural network.
My goal in this stage is to optimize the latency of the audio signal preprocessing so that it is at least as fast as the inference latency of the neural network (which on the same hardware is of 0.25ms).
It is not important that tensorflow knows the grandients of the audio preprocessing,since the training starts after the model is fed a spectrogram that has been calculated separately.